# Determine type of serialised data type in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am writing two programs in Haskell, `readFoo.hs` and `writeFoo.hs`.

`Foo` is a datatype defined like this:

```
data Structure = ListStruct | TreeStruct

data Foo t = Foo {
    struct  :: Structure
  , content :: t Int
}
```

where `t` is either a list or a tree.

`writeFoo.hs` writes a value of type `Foo t`, where `t` gets determined by an option:

```
main = case option of
    ListStruct -> writeListFoo
    TreeStruct -> writeTreeFoo
```

Now i want `readFoo.hs` to read the written file and run a function depending on the structure of `Foo`:

```
main = do
    foo <- readFoo
    case struct foo of
        ListStruct -> runListFoo
        TreeStruct -> runTreeFoo

runListFunction :: Foo [] -> IO ()
runTreeFunction :: Foo Tree -> IO ()
```

but this fails, because obviously `foo` can't be of type `Foo []` and `Foo Tree` at the same time.

Is there a way to do what i want?

Comment: you could use an existential type but it's probably easier to have a function that is first reading the `Structure` of your file and then use this as a control flow

Comment: btw: why don't you use `data Foo = FooList [Int] | FooTree (Tree Int)` instead?

Comment: I think what you are trying to have is some kind of dependent-pair (there is a nice encoding trick in one of the answers in this reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/7tbw7d/what_i_whish_i_knew_haskell_and_dependent_pairs/) - basically you want your `readFoo` to return `(a : Structure, Foo (a -> t))` where the type-parameter for `Foo` *depends* on the value of the first component.

Comment: I deleted my answer as it seems I misunderstood - in order to help us give you a helpful answer, please could you give more detail, in particular the type of `readFoo` (and perhaps its implementation if it isn't too complex)? PS I think @Carsten's suggestion to rewrite your `Foo` type would make whatever you are doing a lot easier.

Comment: @Carsten In reality the type `Foo` has much more fields, so i would have to copy them for each data constructor or use some kind of wrapper. Also i wanted to keep the underlying data structure of `Foo` extensible.

Comment: not if you collect the common ones into it's own record/type

Comment: another way is to make your `readFoo` a bit more generic: make it return `-> a` (or `IO a`) and add arguments to transform the cases you want supported: `Foo [] -> a` and `Foo Tree -> a` -  this pushes the `case`  into `readFoo` where you should have no issues with choosing types

Answer (score 2):

It would appear that you have a mistake in your formulation. The type `Foo` you've defined allows you write terms whose "tag" doesn't match the intended type of data:

```
-- Claims to be a "ListStruct" but the type is actually completely unrelated
badVal1 :: Foo Maybe
badVal1 = Foo ListStruct Nothing

-- Claims to be a "TreeStruct" but the type is actually list
badVal2 :: Foo []
badVal2 = Foo TreeStruct []
```

You can define your type as follows to disallow the above bad values:

```
data Structure x where
  ListStruct :: Structure []
  TreeStruct :: Structure Tree

data Foo s where
  Foo :: Structure s -> s Int -> Foo s
```

Note that with this change, `Structure` explicitly encodes the type of data which it requires.

If you have a `Foo`, but don't know of which type, you can express that as well:

```
data SomeFoo where
  SomeFoo :: Foo s -> SomeFoo
```

and you can operate on such values by pattern matching on the `Structure` argument, which allows you to discover the type of the data:

```
readFooAndDoSomething :: IO ()
readFooAndDoSomething = do
    SomeFoo (Foo struct datum) <- readFoo
    case struct of
        ListStruct -> runListFunction datum
        TreeStruct -> runTreeFunction datum


-- Left to the reader...
readFoo :: IO SomeFoo
runListFunction :: [Int] -> IO ()
runTreeFunction :: Tree Int -> IO ()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately by using GADT's it is very hard for me to make `Foo` an instance of the `Generic` type class, which i need for the `Binary` type class to serialize `Foo`, but i appreciate your help.

Comment: @CifarettoWiggum A `Generic` instance is not the only way to write a `Binary` instance. This is a totally separate question, but: `SomeFoo`, despite being a GADT, is isomorphic to `data Foo' = ListStruct' [Int] | TreeStruct' (Tree Int)`, and that is a regular ADT. You can derived the (perhaps complicated) `Binary Foo'` and write the `Binary Foo` trivially in terms of `Binary Foo'`.